# How can i get data from two input field under a radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where i used a radio button. when user select file, input field of file show and when select text input field of text show. my problem is how can i get data from a radio button which have another two input field.

```
<div class="span7">
    <b>Select File or Link</b>

    <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink1" id="rad1" checked="" />File
    <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink2" id="rad2" />Link
</div>
<div class="span7" id="linkname">
    <b>Press Release link</b>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Press Link" />
</div>

<div class="span7" style="margin-left:42px;display: none;" id="filename">
    <b>Press Release File</b>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</div>
<!--Onselect Radio button -->
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($_GET['Telephone'] == 'filelink1') {
   $val = $_GET['file']; } 
else {
   $val = $_GET['link']; }
```

ps:change the method if you don't use GET

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick event of the the radio button and pass this as argument. 
This will pass the reference to the element which is clicked and by checking its value we can perform our logic. See Below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnTelephoneSelect(radioButton)
        {
            if (radioButton.value=="filelink1") {

                document.getElementById("linkname").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("filename").style.display = "";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("linkname").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("filename").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="span7">
        <b>Select File or Link</b>

        <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink1" id="rad1" checked="" onclick="OnTelephoneSelect(this)"/>File
        <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink2" id="rad2" onclick="OnTelephoneSelect(this)" />Link
    </div>
    <div class="span7" id="linkname" style="display: none;">
        <b>Press Release link</b>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Press Link" />
    </div>

    <div class="span7" style="margin-left:42px;" id="filename">
        <b>Press Release File</b>
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad.....I have done this already now i just want to insert data into database. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May this help you show and hide div elements based on the selection of radio buttons.

```
<div class="span7">
    <b>Select File or Link</b>

    <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink1" id="rad1" checked="" />File
    <input type="radio" name="Telephone" value="filelink2" id="rad2" />Link
</div>


<div class="span7" id="linkname">
<b>Press Release link</b>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Press Link" />
</div>

<div class="span7" style="margin-left:42px;display: none;" id="filename">
<b>Press Release File</b>
<br/>
<input type="file" name="file" />
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="filelink1")
                {
                   $("#filename").hide();
                   $("#linkname").show();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="filelink2")
                {
                   $("#linkname").hide();
                   $("#filename").show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

For live demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaece25/erggb7fy/)

Comment: My problem is , how to get the data from the input field which is selected